# Create hive database and table from Java

Tags: java, hive

Are their any Java libraries that would let me create Hive database and tables from Java? I've googled a lot but could not find any.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by JDBC connections. Just check these link:

1.) [Hive Server1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient) For Hive 0.10 and below.

2.) [Hive server2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients) For Hive 0.11 and above.

Hope it helps...!!!